# Dynamically change css with php

Tags: php, session-variables

I am having issues with changing some inline css dynamically with a php if statement.

I have a form that saves an index to a database. It changes from 0 to 1 when the form is completed. This index is then passed on to a `$SESSION` variable which I then use for the condition inside the if statement.

when I echo the `_SESSION` variable (right after creating it inside an action_page) it outputs the correct value. But when I echo the value in the file where I am trying to do the inline css, nothing gets outputted.

I believe there is something wrong with how I am grabbing the database value

I am echoing `$contact_info` toward the bottom and it is displaying `' '` instead of `'0'` or `'1'`.

Here is my code:

```html
<?php

include('includes/db.php');

if($stmt = $connection->prepare("SELECT contact_info FROM 
    onboarding_checklist WHERE email_address=?")){
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $_SESSION['email']); // session email is working

    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($contact_info);
    if($stmt->errno)
        echo "Fail: " . $stmt->error;
    echo $contact_info; // this comes out blank
    $_SESSION['contact_info'] = $contact_info;
    $stmt->close();
}
else
    echo "Fail: ";
```

Comment: and do you have `session_start()` where you try the inline css? Because you are passing a session variable as parameter to a query

Comment: @Nick OP's query is valid. OP is using `mysqli` not `pdo`

Comment: Check if your $_SESSION['email'] is not empty before the if.

Comment: $_SESSION['email'] is not empty.

Comment: session_start is inside a file called "user_header" that is being 'required' in the file called 'non_approved.php' which also has the file required called 'onboarding_variables.php' (which is the file causing the problem)

Comment: Also, there are no errors saying session index does not exist, its simply coming out blank.